# Using different formulas depending on the column the value input is found

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to make a calculator. The calculator will output values based on a formula depending on what column the input is found in....I have 3 different columns, all with email addresses in them. The idea is you plug in your email address, it looks up your email and finds it in column A, B or C. Then based on that it will do a few sumifs, among other things, depending on which column you are in (the calculation changes per column)

How can I do this? Also, a more basic question: how can I reference worksheets in VBA? (the vba would be in sheet 2, while the data it looks up, and sums etc is in sheet 1).

I hope this is specific enough, I do not have any code to start us off, mainly because I do not know where to start, and do not want to limit myself with poorly constructed code.

Also, I'm told this can be done without VBA, using some little known built in function...but idk what it is, so I can't look up how to use it...VBA or built in function- whichever gets the job done!

Thanks

Comment: When you search for the email addresses with a `VLOOKUP` you could use nested `IF` with `ISERROR` / `ISNA` to check if the email was found in a column.

Comment: yes that would get me WHAT column it is in, but I'd also like to calculate based on that answer. I could use nested If statements, but as the calculations are quite arduous and complicated, I was trying to see if there is a more elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

I would use an index combined with match for the first two arguments of the index function. From there, you will be able to determine which column you're in (whether you're in A B or C). Once you have that value, it's pretty much simple programming with rudimentary if statements. Let me know if I can help you some more.

Comment: I've done many Index matches, but they return a value from the column (in this case it would return the email)...but you wouldn't know which column it is in. If you try an IsERROR, you can return a value if there is an error. So if you do an IfError, to try and find when the index match is true, you still can't return the column....in essence, I still cannot return the column name (it is the cells A1, B1 and C1 which lists the column name)


EDIT: nvm use an if statement index match, where if false is aother index match...it is sloppy work but i'll get it done

Comment: Do you need any other help? If you show me what you have, I can possibly help you some more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand it but check out:

http://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/08/16/search-for-a-cell-in-a-table-and-then-display-the-column-title-in-excel/

It works. It will return the column heading without a series of cascading "IFERROR" statements.

You will have to test the results with a series of cascading "IF" statements to apply the formula you want, but I don't see any way around that.

NOTE: If the same email address appears more than once, it will only return the first column heading.